# Get month name from two digit month number

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to get month name from two digit month number (ex- 09). I tried with this code. But it doesn't work. The code give current month name only. What are the correct code for it?

```
 var formattedMonth = moment().month('09').format('MMMM');
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You want to pass the month when you create the Moment object:

```
var formattedMonth = moment('09', 'MM').format('MMMM'); // September

moment(
    '09',           // Desired month
    'MM'            // Tells MomentJs the number is a reference to month
).format('MMMM')    // Formats month as name
```

Answer (score 62):

While there's nothing wrong with Kevin's answer, it is probably more correct (in terms of efficiency) to obtain the month string without going through a `moment` object.

```
var monthNum = 9;   // assuming Jan = 1
var monthName = moment.months(monthNum - 1);      // "September"
var shortName = moment.monthsShort(monthNum - 1); // "Sep"
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to pass the month as a number, not text - so...

```
var formattedMonth = moment().month(9).format('MMMM');
console.log(formattedMonth)
```

Result:
October

Comment: Often forgotten is the zero based nature of .month, this had me caught up for a while.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to do it and changing languages (locale), this is what I did

```
let month = moment().month(09).locale('pt-br').format('MMMM');
```