# How to get `Month Name` from `Month number` using `moment.js`

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` in angularjs application for date conversion. i want to print `Month number` as a `Month name`. I have tried as bellow,

```
<p>{{item.ReviewMonth | date : 'MMMM'}}</p>
```

where `item.ReviewMonth` in number formate.

ex-1. `<p>{{5 | date : 'MMMM'}}</p>` where `5` is indicate 'May'
but its print `january` instead of `May`.

ex-2. `<p>{{4 | date : 'MMMM'}}</p>` where `4` is indicate 'April'
but its print `january` instead of `April`.

How can i get correct month name from month number?

Comment: Issue is happen when you try using ng-repeat right?

Comment: yes. i am using 'ng-repeat'.

Comment: Check if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274581/get-month-name-from-two-digit-month-number) helps.

Comment: @alka Answer posted please check

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because when `date` filter trying to convert `5` to `Date` object, `5` will be recognized as milliseconds and will be converted to `1970-01-01T00:00:00.005Z`. Then `date` filter will return `January`.

---

Solution:

```
moment('5', 'M').format('MMMM');
```

or

```
moment('05', 'MM').format('MMMM');
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.testDate = 5;
    $scope.testDate2 = new Date(5);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span>{{testDate | date: 'MMMM'}}</span><br>
  {{testDate2}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get month name from month number using simple javascript:

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var month_number = 1;
alert("The current month is " + monthNames[parseInt(month_number)+1]);
```

Or by using moment js you can get it like:

```
var formattedMonth = moment('09', 'MM').format('MMMM'); // September

moment(
    '09',           // Desired month
    'MM'            // Tells MomentJs the number is a reference to month
).format('MMMM')    // Formats month as name
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use momentjs methods inside your angular view you can use [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).

In your case, you [`amParse`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amparse-filter) filter to specify that your input should be interpreted as month number and then you can use [`amDateFormat`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amdateformat-filter) to choose how to display the parsed date.

Here a working sample:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {};
  $scope.item.ReviewMonth = 5;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <p>{{item.ReviewMonth | amParse:'M' | amDateFormat:'MMMM'}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make simple directive for month name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<any ng-repeat="x in item">
    <my-dir myindex="x.ReviewMonth"></my-dir>
</any>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.item = 
    [
        {
            ReviewMonth:"9"
        },
        {
            ReviewMonth:"2"
        },
        {
            ReviewMonth:"3"
        },
        {
            ReviewMonth:"4"
        },
        {
            ReviewMonth:"5"
        },
        {
            ReviewMonth:"6"
        },
        {
            ReviewMonth:"7"
        },
        {
            ReviewMonth:"7"
        }
    ]
});

app.directive('myDir', function () 
{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myindex: '='
    },
    template:'<div>{{myindex}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        var months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","june","july","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"];
        scope.myindex = months[scope.myindex];
    }
  };
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```